# Unable to access cars2010 dataframe from R AppliedPredictiveModeling package

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to access the cars2010 dataframe that is listed in the R AppliedPredictiveModeling package:

This is partial output of the data(package="AppliedPredictiveModeling") command:

```
Data sets in package ‘AppliedPredictiveModeling’:

ChemicalManufacturingProcess
                 Chemical Manufacturing Process
                 Data
abalone          Abalone Data
bio (hepatic)    Hepatic Injury Data
cars2010 (FuelEconomy)
                 Fuel Economy Data
cars2011 (FuelEconomy)
                 Fuel Economy Data
cars2012 (FuelEconomy)
                 Fuel Economy Data
```

I am able to access another dataframe in the package:
segmentationOriginal but not the cars201x dataframes

```
> library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
> data(cars2010)
Warning message:
In data(cars2010) : data set ‘cars2010’ not found
> data(segmentationOriginal)
> data(cars2011)
Warning message:
In data(cars2011) : data set ‘cars2011’ not found
> data(cars2012)
Warning message:
In data(cars2012) : data set ‘cars2012’ not found
```

Do you know the explanation of this? I do have the latest package - 1.1.6

Thanks

Comment: I did find the fueleconomy package that has similar data so I will use that, but I don't understand why I am unable to access the car data in the AppliedPredictiveModeling package.

Comment: When you load the FuelEconomy data, it will give you access to the cars2010 data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at  `?FuelEconomy`   What you need is

```
data(FuelEconomy)
dim(cars2010)
[1] 1107   14
```

Comment: Is the FuelEconomy package the same as fueleconomy? I have fueleconomy installed and get this when trying the dim command: dim(cars2010)
Error: object 'cars2010' not found

Comment: No.   FuelEconomy is a data set in the AppliedPredictiveModeling package.   load AppliedPredictiveModeling   with `library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)`  then type the commands in my answer.

Comment: BTW   R is case sensitive   fueleconomy != FuelEconomy

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you. I think I misunderstood that cars2010 (FuelEconomy) was referring to FuelEconomy as the dataframe not cars2010. But I am confused, what is FuelEconomy and what is cars2010 as far as R structures in this package? Can you help me with that? I surmise that cars2010 is a matrix and FuelEconomy but am checking on that.